# Incompatible types in animation support library

Tags: android, android-animation, incompatibility

I tried to implement [this animation library](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal), but I am still getting incompatilible error on SupportAnimator and don't know how to solve it.

[image]

Here's the code (copy pasted from the library github):

```
actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    View myView = view.findViewById(R.id.awesome_card);

                    // get the center for the clipping circle
                    int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
                    int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

                    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
                    int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

                    SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView,cx,cy,0,finalRadius);

                    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    animator.setDuration(1500);
                    animator.start();
                }
    });
```

imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;

import io.codetail.animation.SupportAnimator;
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Try to clean&rebuild your project.

Comment: It's happening even in new clean project..

Comment: Can you post your class imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change SupportAnimator to Animator. It should work

**Update:**
please make sure you import this library:

```
import io.codetail.animation.ViewAnimationUtils;
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, but only for API 22 and higher. That SupportAnimator from the library that i have linked should work for lower APIs

Comment: Thanks a lot, there was normal ViewAnimationUtils imported and I didn't know it has special import..